# What happens to gear and clothing when you use the Kitsune’s Change Shape ability? (Or other polymorph effects in general)

Tags: pathfinder-2e, equipment, races, shapeshifting

I was trying to search on the Archives of Nethys for what happens to a character's clothing/gear when they use [change shape](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=701) .  I couldn't find anything on the specific ability or even [polymorph rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=127) and [transmutation rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=269) in general, so I must be missing something!

The only other theory I could come up with is I'm not actually missing anything, there are no rules for your gear changing/merging/etc. so you have to strip before turning to a fox or back, and you better have adaptive clothing that fits both your tailed form and your not form if you have a tailless form...Of course, that would mean all of those battle polymorph spells would be a bit awkward to use, like [dinosaur form](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=72) would seem rather awkward to have to strip first!

In contrast,  the [enlarge spell](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=102) actually does explicitly say what happens to your gear, which unfortunately lends credence to the "if it doesn't say,  it doesn't do anything" interpretation, but that doesn't really seem like it would be RAI for combat polymorph abilities.

So...am I missing something, or is it really true that RAW most polymorph effects don't change what you are wearing with you?  I am particularly interested in the Kitsune example, as I've been chatting with a friend who is playing one in a 2E game right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Gear is Absorbed for Battle Forms

When casting something like *dinosaur form* or the kitsune's [Rampaging Form](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2630) to gain the effects of *animal form*, there's a [general rule](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=303) about what happens to gear when entering a battle form spell.

> If you take on a battle form with a polymorph spell, the special statistics can be adjusted only by circumstance bonuses, status bonuses, and penalties... **Your gear is absorbed into you**; the constant abilities of your gear still function, but you can't activate any items.

Turning into a fox with Change Shape using one of the various [heritages](https://2e.aonprd.com/Heritages.aspx?Ancestry=38) duplicates the effects of *pest form*, another such battle form polymorph spell.

A tailless kitsune's Change Shape isn't a battle form spell or duplicating the effects of one, so your gear would remain when shifting between forms. This allows you to keep your weapons and armor when in your other humanoid form, which would extend to other gear and clothes.

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how I missed that one line in the polymorph rules, the exact thing I was looking for.  So your gear doesn't change into a tailless form, but that means it doesn't adapt at all for things like your tails...versatile clothing/armor choices?

Answer (score 5):

### You had it and missed it; they're absorbed

[Polymorph](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=127) rules include

> Your gear is absorbed into you; the constant abilities of your gear still function, but you can't activate any items.

Clothing is a form of gear, so covered by this... or, at the very least, this sets the precedent that GM's should follow even if they don't consider it to be gear.

Comment: Missed it on the battle form,  yeah...but not the alternate form. Hmm